# How to read a text file line by line using Expo File System?

Tags: javascript, react-native, file, expo

I have a large `.txt` file (815 KB) where each line has a number, for example:

```
013
17
7783014
8156
```

I want to read it and add each number to a local database table.

I managed to read it using `FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(file.uri)` but it is a lot of data, it doesn't seem like a good idea to create an array using `.split('\n')` and then iterate it.

There is an `options` object in the [docs](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v38.0.0/sdk/filesystem/#filesystemreadasstringasyncfileuri-options), but I don't know the number of bytes (`length`) that each line has.

What can I do to read line by line or at least a more performative approach than reading the whole file, then creating an array and then iterating it?